# select with IN gives wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Field editors `value '3,2,4'`

sql statement

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where '3' in (editors)
```

result 1 row = correct

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where '2' in (editors)
```

result 0 row = not correct.

I presume the `value '3,2,4'` is treated as a string, how to solve this?

Comment: Well what happens if you try: `select * from table where '2' in ('2','3','4')` ?

Comment: look up prepared statements.  Or if you are in MySQL look up `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: This looks like MySQL. You will need `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', editors)` but the _real solution_ is to change the table structure to normalize the `editors` into a proper one-to-many relationship.  This is almost certain to cause you future headaches bigger than this one. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: FYI sidenote for the [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function: The syntax is `WHERE column IN('value1','value2','value3')` - [From the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) `SELECT val1 FROM tbl1 WHERE val1 IN ('1','2','a');`

Comment: Thanks, find_in_set is what i needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), or a hideous construct like

```
  WHERE editors='2' 
    OR editors LIKE '2,%'
    OR editors LIKE '%,2,%'
    OR editors LIKE '%,2'
```

Right now your query is being interpreted as

```
 WHERE '2' IN ('1,2,3')
 a.k.a
 WHERE '2' = '1,2,3'
```

and not

```
 WHERE '2' IN ('1', '2', '3')
 a.k.a.
 WHERE '2' = '1' OR '2' = '2' OR '2' = '3'
```

like you want it to.
     WHERE